# Permissive CORS policy: Possible to retrieve and parse a response for cross-domain, authenticated request?

Tags: ajax, security, rest, cross-domain, cors

I signed up to ask this question after reading dozens of great posts on this site.  Here is my unanswered question which is admittedly application security focused:

For a site which returns the following headers upon invoking a REST service:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Recognizing such a permissive CORS policy is bad practice for services which return sensitive data, I nevertheless must prove whether or not it is possible for a threat actor to invoke the **authenticated** REST service (cookie auth) on the behalf of an authenticated victim such that the threat actor has visibility into the response.

I understand this flag instructs the browser to send relevant cookies along with the cross-domain request:

```
withCredentials: true
```

I have observed that browsers refuse to allow a threat actor to interpret the returned response, meaning the JSON objects are returned to the browser (as evidenced by a proxy or packet capture) but can never reach the DOM as accessible by the threat actor him or herself.

For example, Chrome produces the message, "*Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true*" when I invoke the aforementioned REST service via jQuery.  If I attempt JSONP I receive the message, "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :* " because I do not have access to modify the REST service logic to return the proper callback string.

**Is it truly impossible for the threat actor to successfully leverage the overly-permissive CORS policy to invoke the REST service and retrieve/parse/return its response on the behalf of the victim's authenticated session?**

I fear that:

- I am unaware of a trick or two
- Some browsers might not actively prevent such an "attack"

Any insight is greatly appreciated as I am not a developer -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use wildcarding when accepting a credentialed request.

> when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Also it looks like you need to set the following header to be sent as a response from the REST service `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, you can add in a .htaccess :

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.*)$" origin_is=$0 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

This directive add a Acess-control-allow-origin valued with the domain name in then request. It copies, in the response header, the value of the Origin request.